# Angular - Changing a components style depending on ngIf result

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-card that essentially has two columns inside of it; one column for displaying the image and the other for the mat-card contents. I currently set the two columns widths to half of their containers width to equally space them inside of the mat-card.

I am trying to modify my html code so that if the returned image path is empty, the mat-card contents occupy the entire width of the mat-card. I've tried doing so using the [ngClass] below but couldn't get it to work.

Is there an alternate way of doing this?

Below is my html code, I set the width of the two columns to half their containers width in the css file.

```
      <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z1" id="card-div" >

        <div class="img-container" *ngIf="blog.imagePath != ''" [ngClass]="blog.imagePath === '' ? 'width': '0%'">
          <img [src]="blog.imagePath" [alt]="">
        </div>

        <div class="card-content" [ngClass]="blog.imagePath === '' ? 'width': '80%'">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title> {{ blog.title }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>
            Published: {{blog.dateCreated}} <br>
            Author: {{blog.author}}
          </mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <hr>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p >{{ blog.content }}</p>
          <mat-action-row >
            <button mat-raised-button  *ngIf="adminIsAuthenticated" (click)="onDelete(blog.blogId)">Delete</button>
            <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="adminIsAuthenticated"  [routerLink]="['/edit', blog.blogId]">Edit</button>
            <button mat-raised-button >Read More</button>
          </mat-action-row>
        </mat-card-content>
      </div>

      </mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[ngClass]` helps you to add some CSS classes to an element, while in your code you are trying to add `width` property that is set to `80%`.
If you wanna use a `[ngClass]` then you can write it like so

```
[ngClass]="{ yourClassName: blog.imagePath === ''}"
```

and in CSS or SCSS file specify this class like so

```
.yourClassName {
 width: 80%;
}
```